# Explanation on equations please

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

I've got seemingly two different equations for velocity in orbit:

$$v_1 = \sqrt{ \frac{2GM}{R}} $$

and $$v = \sqrt{ \frac{Gm_e}{R}}$$

What is the difference between these two? I'm quite sure that $G$ is the gravitational constant, $m_e$ is the mass of the earth. $R$ is the radius of orbit in both cases. I'm not sure what the sub script $1$ is but it has something to do with energy conservation.

Comment: $v_1$ is the [escape velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity). If you throw a rock straight upward with this velocity, the rock with escape to infinity. $v$ is the orbital speed for an object to rotate around earth in a circular orbit w/o falling back to earth.

Comment: Thank you very much! That clears it up perfectly. Please make this an "answer" so I can accept as best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment turned answer per request.

- $v_1$ is the [escape velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity). If you throw a rock straight upward with this velocity, the rock with escape to infinity.
- $v$ is the orbital speed for an object to rotate around earth in a circular orbit of radius $R$ without falling back to earth.